# Expression in ssrs report tooltip that shows current week period when hover over fiscalperiod column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am writing an expression in ssrs report, that if i hover my cursor over fiscalperiod column it shows the actual week period.

```
 `=Format(DateAdd("d", -(DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,
DateSerial(IIf(Month(Today) < 10, Year(Today)+1, Year(Today)),
Month(DateSerial(IIf(Month(Today) < 10, Year(Today)+1, Year(Today)),
InStr(1, "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", Mid(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 4, 3)) \ 3 + 1, 1)), 1),
vbSunday)-2 ) + ((CInt(Right(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 2))-1)*7),
DateSerial(IIf(Month(DateSerial(IIf(Month(Today) < 10, Year(Today), Year(Today)-1),
InStr(1, "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", Mid(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 4, 3)) \ 3 + 1, 1)) < 10, Year(Today), Year(Today)-1),
Month(DateSerial(IIf(Month(DateSerial(IIf(Month(Today) < 10, Year(Today), Year(Today)-1),
InStr(1, "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", Mid(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 4, 3)) \ 3 + 1, 1)) < 10, Year(Today), Year(Today)-1),
InStr(1, "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", Mid(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 4, 3)) \ 3 + 1, 1)), 1)),
"dd.MM.yyyy") & " - " &
Format(DateAdd("d", 6 - (DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,
DateSerial(IIf(Month(Today) < 10, Year(Today)+1, Year(Today)),
Month(DateSerial(IIf(Month(Today) < 10, Year(Today)+1, Year(Today)),
InStr(1, "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", Mid(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 4, 3)) \ 3 + 1, 1)), 1),
vbSunday)-2) + ((CInt(Right(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 2))-1)*7),
DateSerial(IIf(Month(DateSerial(IIf(Month(Today) < 10, Year(Today), Year(Today)-1),
InStr(1, "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", Mid(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 4, 3)) \ 3 + 1, 1)) < 10, Year(Today), Year(Today)-1),
Month(DateSerial(IIf(Month(DateSerial(IIf(Month(Today) < 10, Year(Today), Year(Today)-1),
InStr(1, "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", Mid(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 4, 3)) \ 3 + 1, 1)) < 10, Year(Today), Year(Today)-1),
InStr(1, "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", Mid(Fields!FiscalPeriod.Value, 4, 3)) \ 3 + 1, 1)), 1)),
"dd.MM.yyyy")`
```

Fiscalyear start from Oct end on Sep next year, for example if it start on oct- 2020 then it will end on sep 2021. My problem here is, for the year 2021 my weeks are starting on sunday but for 2020 it start on friday, because it is counting from 1st jan of 2021. How to modify it so that it count day from 1st jan for each calender seprately means for 2021 form 01-01-2021 and for 2020 from 01-01-2020.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not already have one, I would create a date/calendar table with all the dates with fiscal years/weeks etc in it. Then you can simply join to it in your dataset query and get the data you want directly in the dataset. The tooltip would then simply display the new column.

If you don't already have a date table, this link is one of many that describe how to create one easily ( https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/ )

The blog is a bit long but if you scroll about 1/4 of the way down you'll see the final script that generates the table. You can adjust it take into account when your years start or if not generate each year individually to get the desired results.